# What advantages do the different copilots have?

Tags: sega-genesis, desert-strike-return-to-the-gulf

Before starting the game, you can scroll through the list of available copilots to choose to have on your mission. By default, we are paired with Xavier Thomas, or 'X-man', seen below:

[image: Copilot 'X-man's ID badge and description]

There are a few other copilots to choose from, and their textual description tends to mention their markmanship and winch skills. Comparing X-Man to Mr D, one is excellent with the winch whilst the other apparently jams it in the heat of battle.

[image: Copilot 'Mr D's ID badge and description]

A [strategy guide](http://www.cheatcc.com/psp/sg/desert_strike.txt) over on CheatCC mentions the copilots briefly:

> There are only two copilots worth using: Lt Keith Michaels and Lt Carlos Valdez. [snip] Valdez is a fantastic marksman, and he's pretty good with the winch. [snip] Michaels is a decent 
>   substitute since his gunning is only a little worse, and gunning is the most important attribute here.

However, I've *never* noticed a difference between the different copilots, and choosing different ones has never impacted my gameplay. So does this guide speak the truth? If so, how do the different copilots stack up against one another?

Comment: I've added the genesis tag, because the game has been remade on a few different consoles (inlcuding but not limited to the Gameboy, Atari, and gameboy advance), and I'm addressing the Genesis version